# Using is siunitx, how do I put symbols in the number, e.g. to format $\mu_0$

Tags: siunitx

The permeability of free space

I have

```
$\mu_0$ =  4$\pi$ $\times$ \SI{E-7}{\volt\second\per\ampere\per\metre}
```

because

```
$\mu_0$ =  \SI{4$\pi$ E-7}{\volt\second\per\ampere\per\metre}
```

How do I format it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I really understand the question, but it's a single equation, so put in a single pair of `$ ... $`, don't write each individual character in a separate pair of dollar signs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

$\mu_0 =  4\pi \times \SI{E-7}{\volt\second\per\ampere\per\metre}$

$\mu_0 =  \SI{4\pi E-7}{\volt\s\per\ampere\per\m}$

\end{document}
```

If this does not work for you, try what Joseph mentioned in comments, i.e.

```
$\mu_0 =  \SI[parse-numbers=false]{4\pi E-7}{\volt\s\per\ampere\per\m}$
```

[image]

Comment: I think you want `\SI[parse-numbers = false]`, then the `4\pi` can go into the number part.

Comment: @JosephWright `\pi` works even without `parse-numbers=false`, actually ... (Adding MWE in a second.)